# Not able to print debug message while unit testing in Flutter

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, testing, clean-architecture

I am testing a pretty straightforward use-case in Flutter. Inside the use-case class, I have a function that I'm invoking from my test. And I want to add some debug print statements to print the value of some variables inside the function of use-case. But it's not getting printed anywhere. How can I achieve this?

The function in Use-case.

```
Future<Either<Failure, List<Contest>>> call(NoParams params) async {
final result = await repository.getAllContests();
final currentDateTime = DateTime.now();
List<Contest> ongoingContests = [];

result.fold(
    (l) => throw ServerException(),
    (allContestList) => () {
          for (var contest in allContestList) {
            var contestStartTime = DateTime.parse(contest.start_time);
            var contestEndTime = DateTime.parse(contest.end_time);
            print(contestEndTime); //print statement
          }
        });

return Right(ongoingContests);
```

}
}

The test function

```
test('Should return only the ongoing contests', () async {
  when(mockHomepageRepository.getAllContests()).thenAnswer((_) async =>
      const Right([tContest, tOngoingContest, tUpcomingContest]));

  final result = await getOngoingContests(NoParams()); //invoking the function

  expect(result, const Right([tOngoingContest]));
  verify(mockHomepageRepository.getAllContests());
  verifyNoMoreInteractions(MockHomepageRepository());
});
```